How can I implement custom frames for resizing for borderless main window in PyQt5?
I want to implement it because this is how I can track mouse entering to frames. Then I can change cursor type to changing size (horizontal, vertical and diagonal). I could implement it through tracking mouse position in one window but I don`t know how to track mouse position. As I see there are two different types of solutions.
The first one is to implement it through QGridLayout (9 grids - 8 frames and 1 main window). I tried to make it through defining fixed sizes for diagonal frames, fixed widths for left and right frames and fixed heights for top and bottom frames. But then the main window doesn`t expanding to its full available size.
Second one is through 1 big frame and the main window. The main window is located in center on top of big frame. But I don`t know how to implement it. Tbh, I even didn't tried

To get mouse move events you need to call setMouseTracking(True) and then properly override mouseMoveEvent() so that you change cursor only when no buttons are pressed, otherwise call the default implementation. The grid layout approach should work, so I suggest you to [edit] your question and provide a [mre] based on your attempt.

mouseMoveEvent() works only when I drag. Even when I'm using setMouseTracking(True)

No, if you properly called setMouseTracking(True), mouseMoveEvent() will always be called, unless you did any of the above for the wrong target or you have other widgets handling mouse events in their place, which is why we need a MRE as requested above.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
